# Why doesn't my website work on bigger screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a landscaping company in Holland and designed a website for it, I uploaded it a few months ago, and had no problems (of course i tested it on several devices before uploading), but recently I have been receiving comments and mails saying that the site is out of proportions and that some parts of the site (images, tex, etc) cover other parts, such as the contact information, so immediately I started to look in the code and try and figure out what was going on, I noticed that on my own computer, phone and some other devices from colleagues, everything looked fine, but apparently on computers with bigger screens than mine is where the problem is happening.

I have looked into the code, and couldn't find anything that could be the problem, i have tested it on several places such as google insights, and it all seems to be fine, but still it wont work on bigger screens.

I want to ask if anybody with a little spare time could please take a visit on the site, and if somebody has the same problem please give me advice over what it could be, I'm really out of ideas, and I think I'm losing possible customers over this.

My website is [www.vossenatuurlijketuinen.nl](http://www.vossenatuurlijketuinen.nl), its designed totally in html and CSS.

If anybody can help i would really appreciate it, I will keep on trying to solve it, and if i cant find a solution, perhaps i will have to hire somebody to look in to it, although i'd rather keep doing it myself...

edit: i have scanned through the entire code again, and still cant seem to find whats causing the problem, i consider using w3.css as sugested by @mike510a below.
the only thing i noticed that i think might have to do something with this, although i dont really know why this would be a problem, is that i have this in the head of all of my html files:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1264px, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and this right after opening the body:

```html
<div style="min-width: 1264px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

i thought it may be getting all out of place on displays bigger than 1264px, but changing the number to a highter one only makes the page look bigger on smaller screens...

edit 2:
i ended up adding this media query to the css, which fixed the problem for chrome, but on IE it doesn't change a thing...

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1364px) {
 body {zoom:150%;}
}
```

Comment: You should use responsive design.

Comment: Also consider using **w3.css** to layout your CSS elements -- see:  https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp    for information on how to use **w3.css**

Comment: hello @mike510a, thanks for your reply, i initially started with a responsive design, but had to move to a different method, because of the lightboxes i use in the gallery, i tried countless different ones, and couldn't manage to get one working on a responsive design, but i will have a look in the link you send me, thanks a lot

Comment: i had a similar issue and solved it with w3.css easily @Nook

Comment: The problem is really the fact that everyone's screens are different sizes, so by using `px` values instead of `%` values  will cause the page to be rendered incorrectly.  Check out `flexboxes`  as another answer to your problem

Comment: ill fix your site for you if you want to hire me :)  email mike@datafault.net if interested

Comment: i have been working on making it responsive for a while, but the problem i keep facing with this is that i the ligthboxes go out of order, i managed to fix that by making them responsive too, but one thing that still is a problem then, is the resizing of the text, and the menu, i cant seem to get those to scale down or up equally, so it keeps going out of proportions, isn't there a way to tell the brower to show the page at a specific px width? so it shows equally on different sizes of screen, just zoomed in or out. thanks for all the response by the way

Comment: thanks for all the response by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution could be to use **w3.css** instead of your current CSS

**Notice how the Content fits exactly to the page, even when you click on fulll screen.**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


<div class="w3-container w3-teal w3-card-2">
  <h1>My Car</h1>
</div>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_car.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">

<div class="w3-container">
  <p>A car is a wheeled, self-powered motor vehicle used for transportation.</p>
</div>

<div class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <p>My footer information</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this could be an option, but it would mean having to re write a big part of the code to make my website work with this w3.css, i will keep it as an option. thanks for the reply

Comment: not really. w3.css is super easy to learn and use -- you'll find that your whole website can be converted very quickly if you read the documentation first and learn all of the available options

Comment: its literally as simple as adding `class="w3-left"` and  `class="w3-center"`    to different elements